# In XCrawl, does grandstanding have any short term effects?

Tags: d20-system, xcrawl

In XCrawl, you can grandstand to the crowd or mug for the camera during a dungeon crawl.  There are a lot of rules around that - Perform skills, etc - but it seems like the only effect I can find is a long term Fame bonus if you make 5 successful checks.  Does it have some other effect, Mojo bonuses or the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bonus of fame IS the bonus. It is added to various non-performance rolls outside the dungeon-arena. Fame also affects one's appearance fees. (P.122)

So the whole point of grandstanding is to get your fame up by making the crowd like you. Which, by the way, makes it easier to please the next crowd.

Comment: It just seems like having the crowd with you would be worth some short term performance bonus as well. Especially since you have to make five consecutive checks to get the Fame bonus - the way I read that is if you fail one (very likely in a d20 system) you're starting over. And a single dungeon isn't actually that big, are you grandstanding like more than once per room?  Is everyone?

Comment: Well, once you have fame 10+, it is gonna spiral up and up. A starting character, of 3rd level, can have up to a +11 in perform, if they want it, and its a class skill. (5 ranks, +2 from feat, +4 from stat 18.) Cross class, it's still +7 (2 ranks, +2 from feat, +3 from stat 16).  So it's possible for such characters to stand a decent chance of doing it. But once they complete a few dungeons, it rapidly becomes quite doable to make 5 in a row... Besides, DC's can be as low as 10 for the crowd... So you play to the crowd at home.